# "ERROR: You have not provided a valid image (AMI) value" in knife ec2 server create

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am trying out the https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2. After bundle installing the gems, i configured the knife.rb to something like this:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "username9999"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/username9999"
validation_client_name   "name_aws_test-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/name_aws_test-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/name_aws_test"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]

knife[:availability_zone]   = "US West (Oregon)"
#knife[:region]              = "Oregon"
knife[:image]               = "ami-eb99b2db"
knife[:flavour]             = "t2.micro"

knife[:aws_access_key_id] = "AKXXXXXXTTTTTTXXXX"
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = "PrabchdthsoelfmhuhgyE"
knife[:aws_ssh_key_id] = 'ec2-test'
```

now the knife ec2 server create -r something returns this:
ERROR: You have not provided a valid image (AMI) value

I have made sure that i am not faulting on the ami that i copied from the community ami's. So say this is the community thing: 
Centos6-template-clean-hvm - ami-07d4f737

i am taking the ami as ami-07d4f737. Then due to the persistent error, i have created a new private ami for myself. It still returns the same. Any suggestions?

PS: verbosity returns nothing useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be due to one of following reasons:

1. You have correct AMI ID but a wrong region. Check whether the "Oregon" region has the AMI ID that you are using. Also, the region name is case-sensitive.
2. You have a wrong AMI ID
3. Probably, you do not have privileges to access this AMI, but in that case it would have said permission/Access denied kinda error.

Besides, in your `knife.rb` settings, the value for "Availability Zone" looks wrong. There is no such AZ called "US West (Oregon)".

For Oregon region, it is either `us-west-2a` or `us-west-2b` or `us-west-2c`

Comment: haven't been able to try out your inputs. i will do it asap and will post back. thanks!

Comment: you are right the AMI seem to be not matching with the AZ/Regions etc...  This site list all the ami's and their details, which is very helpfull. http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/    Then i was looking CentOS images - looks like centos aws ami are not available for free ?  http://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS

Comment: CentOS AMIs are available for free.